# There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Tags: r

Recently I want to stimulate a flip coin game. A coin starts with "head" and three people to decide whether to flip the coin or not. Finally, I want to count the numbers that are "head"

Here is the stimulation of the game:

```
head <- rbind(c(0),c(1))

flip <- rbind(c(0,1),c(1,0))

result <- c()

for (i in 1:1000){
  x <- rbinom(1,1,0.5)
    if (x == 0) {
      count <- flip %*% head
    } 
    else{
      count <- head
    }

  x <- rbinom(1,1,0.5)
    if (x == 0) {
      count <- flip %*% count
    } 
    else{
      count <- count
    }

  x <- rbinom(1,1,0.5)
    if (x == 0) {
      count <- flip %*% count
    } 
    else{
      count <- count
    }
result[[i]] <- count
}
result
```

Then, I want to count the result that is head

```
for (i in result){
  if (i == head) {
    check <- check+1
  }
}
```

However, it says `There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)`

I tried to do this

```
ifelse(result == head, check+1, check)
```

But it says

```
'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

How can I fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: For me, it runs with no warnings.

Comment: What were the warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use

```
sum(sapply(result, function(x) sum(x == head) ==2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sapply` to count number of heads.

```
sum(sapply(result, function(x) all(x == head)))
#[1] 516
```

To calculate ratio/percentage :

```
mean(sapply(result, function(x) all(x == head)))
#[1] 0.516
```